Kotlin top level functions break Xcode 16 previews in KMP projects?
I experience that if I have top level functions in my Kotlin code in a KMP project and use them in swift like
UtilsKt.doSomethingForMe()

the previews in Xcode 16 are not working and even crashing if they are used. Is something known about this problem? (in Xcode 15 there was no problem with them)
